# get data from table cell ID

Tags: javascript

I have the following table. What do i need to use in JavaScript to read the number from the below cell named "number"?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="number">56656.87</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried the following however it does not work.

```
document.getElementById('number');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property holds the contents of that cell. If you got [object Object] on your last attempt you're almost there. This is how you do it:

```
     var n = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
```

Make sure there's no other number id on that page.

Answer (score 7):

Using raw JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementById('number').innerText;
```

Using jQuery:

```
var text = $('#number').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery:

```
​$(function(){
   alert($("#number").html()); 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fG5nF/

Answer (score 0):

If you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), you can just do this:

```
var number = $("td#number").text();
```